# Nice ODE that has wildly behaving solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can we find an ODE
$$ f^{(n)}(x) + a_{n-1}(x)f^{(n-1)}(x)+  \ldots + a_0(x) f(x) = b(x),$$

with coefficients $a_i(x), b(x)$ in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, bounded in codomain, whose solutions $f(x) \in Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ behave wildly?

---

I'm looking for some **minimal** examples. So hopefully $n$ can be as low as possible. It'd be better if $b \equiv 0$, and all the $a_i$'s are simple enough as polynomials. The more chaotic $f$ is the better.

**EDIT**: A comment below suggests there's none by Picard's theorem.

---

If there's none, would you please refer to a theorem that guarantees nicety? What are some minimal setups for bad solutions to exist for good DEs?

Comment: Your solution will always be $C^{\infty}$ by the Picard-Lindelöf-Theorem.

Comment: @Jake28 Oh yeah.. how about in two variables?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Your equation is linear. The solutions to $n$-th order linear equations (with $b = 0$) are an $n$-dimensional vector space. See any standard differential equations book for this. You haven't specified how "bad" you would like solutions to be, but a typical minimal requirement, but not sufficient, for chaos is 3rd order nonlinear.

Edit: one of the common examples comes from the Rossler system, see Wikipedia, which is a system of 3 first order equations. From them you can derive a really horrible looking 3rd order equation, but this is not usually done because the system is more agreeable for study. The solution trajectories are chaotic and elegant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you give a pointer for the 3rd order nonlinear example? That might be exactly what I'm looking for.